# How to deal with symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 in neatbeans?

Tags: c++, x86-64

Im trying to build a c++ project using Netbeans and h got this error :
Does any one have an idea about this?
Thank you

Comment: did you include all .cpp files when compiling?

Comment: Search the internet for "c++ netbeans symbol not found".  Too many hits to display here.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably forgotten to link with some library as @PhotometricSterio suggested.  That is all I can tell with the information you have provided.  Please provide more details about your error for a more detailed explanation

Comment: Thank you. I am sorry for that